# sendmsg fails with error code 9

Tags: linux, ldap

While running ldapsearch utility in Linux, the "sendmsg" function fails with an error code 9. What does error code 9 represent? The man page does not give information about error codes.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all error codes in this page. http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno . Currently I am taking same result. "send" method works but sendmsg is returning -1 and errno is 9 which means bad file number. I still don't know what the problem is.

```
#define EBADF        9  /* Bad file number */
```